# Как убрать элементы управления в поле input?

Tags: html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дал полю ввода тип "номер", появились стрелочки (под плюсом). Подскажите как их можно убрать? Мешают центрированию текста внутри. Или подскажите иной способ, чтобы в поле можно было вводить только числа.

Comment: ```input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Убрать стрелочки с <input type="number">](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431590/%d0%a3%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81-input-type-number)

Comment: @soledar10
Подскажите еще пожалуйста, как можно ограничить количество символов в строке, как я понял, maxlength работает только на текст, на числа не работает

Comment: для этого используйте аттрибут - ```max="999"```

Comment: @soledar10 тоже не помагает(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-can-i-set-max-length-in-an-html5-input-type-number-element